# Regex match in shell script

Tags: regex, shell

I'm writing a shell script that makes sure my DNS server is looking. Here's the output it tests:

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   galapagos.office
Address: 192.168.140.25
```

Everything but the "galapagos.office" needs to match exactly. The "galapagos.office" part itself doesn't actually matter at all.

I figure I can apply this regex to the output to tell me if it looks how I want:

```
Server: +127\.0\.0\.1\nAddress: +127\.0\.0\.1#53\n\nName:.+\nAddress: 192\.168\.140\.25
```

The thing is I don't really know shell scripting. What's the best way to make sure that regex matches the output of an nslookup command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess of what you actually want

```
awk '/Server/&&$2=="127.0.0.1"{f=1}
       /Address/&&$2=="127.0.0.1#53"{g=1}
       /Address/&&$2=="192.168.140.25"{h=1}
  END{if(h && g && f) print "ok"}' file
```